# More Efficient Way For SQL IN Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have this sql query and this takes very long time to finish. How can i speed this up?

t_inter_specises_interaction has 60k rows and t_pathway has 100k. uniprot_id_1,uniprot_id_2,uniprot_id are varchar types.

In this query, i want to select uniprot_id_1 and uniprot_id_2 which are both present in t_pathway :

```
select distinct uniprot_id_1,uniprot_id_2 from t_intra_species_interaction
where uniprot_id_1 in (select uniprot_id from t_pathway) and
  uniprot_id_2 in (select uniprot_id from t_pathway)
```

In this one, i want to select uniprot_id which is present in the set uniprot_ids returned by the first query above.

```
select distinct uniprot_id,id from t_pathway as t
where uniprot_id in
(
    select distinct uniprot_id_2 from t_intra_species_interaction
    where uniprot_id_1 in (select uniprot_id from t_pathway) and
      uniprot_id_2 in (select uniprot_id from t_pathway)
    union
    select distinct uniprot_id_1 from t_intra_species_interaction
    where uniprot_id_1 in (select uniprot_id from t_pathway) and
      uniprot_id_2 in (select uniprot_id from t_pathway)
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: use exists instead of in

Comment: It's slow because the sub-queries in those `IN()` clauses are being run for each matching row in `t_intra_species_interaction`.

Comment: Viplime there are answers that solve this or your question stand open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subqueries are identical, therefore they can be merged into one, and moved to a join

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.uniprot_id_1, i.uniprot_id_2 
FROM   t_intra_species_interaction i
       INNER JOIN t_pathway p ON p.uniprot_id IN (i.uniprot_id_1, i.uniprot_id_2)
```

**Second query**
It would have be better to open a new question referring to this, but looking at my previous query it should be easy to see that to get your second answer, you only need to get the column from t_pathway instead of t_intra_species_interaction

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.uniprot_id, p.id
FROM   t_intra_species_interaction i
       INNER JOIN t_pathway p ON p.uniprot_id IN (i.uniprot_id_1, i.uniprot_id_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use INNER JOIN:

```
select distinct uniprot_id_1,uniprot_id_2 from t_intra_species_interaction i
inner join t_pathway p1
    on p1.uniprod_id = t.uniprot_id_1 
inner join t_pathway p2
    on p2.uniprod_id = t_uniprot_id_2
```

Comment: You'll have to join `t_pathway` twice, once per `uniprod_id`.

Comment: why should this perform better than in?

Comment: @guido In MySQL in particular, joins often do.

Comment: even on varchar columns?

Answer (score 2):

`EXISTS` or `JOIN` will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select distinct uniprot_id_1,uniprot_id_2
from t_intra_species_interaction I
  join t_pathway P1
    on I.uniprot_id_1 = P1.uniprot_id
  join t_pathway P2
    on I.uniprot_id_2 = P2.uniprot_id
```

or

```
select distinct uniprot_id_1,uniprot_id_2
from t_intra_species_interaction I
where exists (select 1 from t_pathway where uniprot_id = I.uniprot_id_1)
  and exists (select 1 from t_pathway where uniprot_id = I.uniprot_id_2)
```

Comment: Exists would be faster if you use or instead of 2 subqueries

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid But that'd correspond to an `OR` instead of an `AND` operation between the conditions.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, What you mean? Can you explain?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson if you see OP's query he wants to select where `uniprot_id_1,uniprot_id_2` is equal to  same column i.e `uniprot_id`,so or operator will do the job with a single subquery

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid If you do `or` (as another answer suggested before it was changed), you'd only need to match `uniprot_id_1` OR `uniprot_id_2`. The original query want both of them to exist in `t_pathway`, not just either of them.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan My comment wasn't about your answer which correctly is using two subqueries, it was about the comment that suggests using `OR` (ie `uniprot_id = I.uniprot_id_1 OR uniprot_id = I.uniprot_id_2`) instead of the subqueries.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Consider the case where `uniport_id_1` is equal to `uniport_id` but `uniport_id_2` is _not equal_ to any of the `uniport_id`s. That combination of `(uniport_id_1, uniport_id_2)` will be accepted if only 1 `exists` is used.

Comment: @JohnBupit If you read upwards, you'd see that that is my point, I'm not suggesting changing to `OR`, I'm saying it won't work :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a general guildline:

Create three indexes, one on `t_pathway.uniport_id` and one on `t_intra_species_interaction.uniport_id1` and another on `t_intra_species_interaction.uniport_id2`

By this way all the data that you need is in your indexes, and it should be fast

Also converting your in clauses to Left join as Tomas mentioned in his answer

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
select distinct uniprot_id_1, uniprot_id_2
from t_intra_species_interaction
where exists (select uniprot_id from t_pathway
              where uniprot_id_1 = uniprot_id) and
      exists (select uniprot_id from t_pathway
              where uniprot_id_2 = uniprot_id)
```

Comment: You need two `exists`.